# Scala code to insert JSON string to mongo DB

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I have the below `JSON` string,

```
{"card_id" : 75893645814809,"cust_id": 1008,"card_info": {"card_type" : "Travel Card","credit_limit": 126839},"card_dates" : [{"date":"1997-09-09" },{"date":"2007-09-07" }]}
```

and I want to insert this to `MongoDB`. Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? This looks like a "gimme the code" question currently.  It's basically two parts - JSON parsing, and MongoDB integration- which of those are your problem?

Comment: What driver are you using ? `Casbah` should be good enough for this kind of work.

Comment: @Archetpal: I am planning to create DBObject for the JSON string and then insert this to mongoDB. is it ok...or it will be better to use casbah driver..?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
val mongo_url = MongoClientURI("mongo://...")
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(mongo_url)
val db = mongoClient("radar")
val coll = db("job_history")
val job = MongoDBObject("name"-> spark, "status"-> "success")
coll.insert(job)
coll.find().foreach(println)
```

The output will like this:

{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5984b745a63eeeacbcbd301d"} , "id" : 22 , "name" : "shenrf22"}

Answer (score 0):

Using Casbah it is fairly easy. This worked for me. Note that the use of a buffer is not necessary, but in case you insert a large amount of objects sending it in batches will improve performance a lot.

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClientURI
import com.mongodb.util.JSON

val jsonString = """{"card_id" : 75893645814809,"cust_id": 1008,"card_info": {"card_type" : "Travel Card","credit_limit": 126839},"card_dates" : [{"date":"1997-09-09" },{"date":"2007-09-07" }]}"""
val dbObject: DBObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
val mongo = MongoClient(MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
val buffer = new java.util.ArrayList[DBObject]()
buffer.add(dbObject)
mongo.getDB("yourDBName").getCollection("yourCollectionName").insert(buffer)
buffer.clear()
```

Comment: This code is using Java classes in casbah not really a scala code? Do you have a scala version of this code? I did not find Scala implementation for JSON.parse. But casbah scala documentation page says "In general, you should only need the org.mongodb.scala and org.bson namespaces in your code. You should not need to import from the com.mongodb namespace as there are equivalent type aliases and companion objects in the Scala driver."

So this means there should be scala version of above used java classes?