# Scala code to insert JSON string to mongo DB using scala drivers/casbah

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I found some code which can parse JSON document, convert it to BSON and then insert. But this code is implemented using Java classes in casbah. I could not find corresponding implementation in Scala.

Also casbah documentation says *"In general, you should only need the org.mongodb.scala and org.bson namespaces in your code. You should not need to import from the com.mongodb namespace as there are equivalent type aliases and companion objects in the Scala driver. The main exception is for advanced configuration via the builders in MongoClientSettings which is considered to be for advanced users."*

If you see below code and note imports, they are using com.mongodb classes. I can use below code in scala and make it work, but I want to know if there is Scala implementation out there to insert JSON into mongodb.

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClientURI
import com.mongodb.util.JSON

val jsonString = """{"card_id" : 75893645814809,"cust_id": 1008,"card_info": {"card_type" : "Travel Card","credit_limit": 126839},"card_dates" : [{"date":"1997-09-09" },{"date":"2007-09-07" }]}"""
val dbObject: DBObject = JSON.parse(jsonString).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
val mongo = MongoClient(MongoClientURI("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))
val buffer = new java.util.ArrayList[DBObject]()
buffer.add(dbObject)
mongo.getDB("yourDBName").getCollection("yourCollectionName").insert(buffer)
buffer.clear()
```

Reference : [Scala code to insert JSON string to mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018855/scala-code-to-insert-json-string-to-mongo-db)

I found few link online which suggests to use different JSON parser libraries, but none of them seems straightforward even though above ~5 lines of code can insert JSON document in Java. I would like to achieve similar thing in Java.

Comment: Can you please specify what you want to achieve: "I want to know if there is Scala implementation out there to insert JSON into mongoldb" or "I would like to achieve similar thing in Java"? In Java or in scala? Also did you check http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/ ?

Comment: I want to insert json data using scala apis, not using java apis. I have looked at link you shared. It is using java  classes to insert json which is fine. I just want to know if we can achieve this using pure scala classes.